# Generating a new client secret

Tags: google-oauth

Is there a way to change the OAuth2 client secret for our Google app without changing the client ID?

I would like to change the client secret as a security best practice (e.g. when one of our production sys admins leaves the company) without having to get all our clients to re-authorize our app.

All I've found on this forum is how to generate client IDs and secrets for new applications. From what I can see, the only option is to generate a new client ID and secret together, meaning any authorizations obtained with the old client ID are effectively useless.

Comment: Are you sure, this will act as new app and will require all your users to re-authorize the app?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a development app and could no longer use refresh tokens that were previously obtained for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josh from the AdWords team directed me to the "Return to original console" link in the bottom right corner. In that version of the console you are able to reset client secrets.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/twf3O3fg1oA for the cross posting.

Answer (score 0):

Client id and Client secret are a pair, together they are used to create the Refresh token and access tokens that allow your application to access a users data.    If you where to only change the client secret then the refresh token and access token generated wouldn't match the old one.  But any way you can't just change one.

You can create a new client id and Client secret pair for your application and then delete the old one.  But the draw back to this will be that any one that had previously given your application access to there data will be forced to reauthenticate because there current refresh token will no longer work.

While I applaud your sense of security and desire to protect your customers data. There is a fine line between annoying customers and protecting them.   I wonder how big of a chance there is that this person actually stole a bunch of refresh tokens as well as the client id and Client secret for your application?   I also wonder what kind of access your application has and what the damage your former employee could do with the information they may or may not have stolen.  Will it be worth it for them to create a new application to use the refresh token and application credentials?

You need to judge if its worth bothering your customers and forcing them to reauthenticate your application every time someone leaves the company.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm afraid I don't agree. When using a refresh token to request a new access token you must also supply the client_id and client_secret. This mitigates any leak of refresh tokens since they are useless if the client_secret is changed.

Comment: As shown in the [linked groups post from the Adwords API Team](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/twf3O3fg1oA/cM7ObuPhv4YJ), it is now possible to reset the client secret without changing the client ID. What effect will this have on access and refresh tokens generated against the old ID/secret pair?

Comment: In my testing, after resetting the secret (keeping same client ID), existing access and refresh tokens are still usable, provided you use them with the new client secret.