# Will generating a new client secret invalidate existing refresh tokens?

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

As per https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/manage-credentials#reset_client_secret
after reseting the client secret for a particular client id, will the existing refresh tokens still work or the user must reauthorise?

Have tested the same across google products and can see that existing refresh tokens are still valid. Found couple of discussions denoting the same:

1. https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/FbfEA0gC8VU
2. [Generating a new client secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679229/generating-a-new-client-secret)

But couldn't find any official document from google stating the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why refresh tokens should be invalidated after a client secret reset. I don't remember in what form Google issues refresh tokens, but if they're JWTs then it would actually be quite tricky to invalidate them.

If your tests show that these tokens are not invalidated, then I think that you can safely assume, that, for now, this does not happen on a secret reset.